# Notice: Uninitialized string offset:2

Tags: php

```
function forums($name, $id){
$forums = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".prefix."FORUM WHERE FORUM_ID = '$id' ") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>0){
    $rs = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $forums = Array(
        $rs[CAT_ID], $rs[F_STATUS], $rs[F_SUBJECT]
        );
}
if ($name == "CAT_ID"){$nom = 0;}
if ($name == "STATUS"){$nom = 1;}
if ($name == "SUBJECT"){$nom = 2;}


return($forums[$nom]);
mysql_free_result($sql);

}
```

I am getting this error:

> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cp_inc\function.php on line 1589

Comment: First of all, don't use mysql_query.  Use mysqli_query, or better yet use PDO. Second, would you mind telling us what line of your sample code would be 1589

Comment: Use print_r($rs); and chk what rcu getting

Comment: Or maybe its $rs[CAT_ID] should be $rs[0]['CAT_ID'] :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are the quotes?

```
$rs[CAT_ID], $rs[F_STATUS], $rs[F_SUBJECT]
```

try placing one :

```
$rs['CAT_ID'], $rs['F_STATUS'], $rs['F_SUBJECT']
```